# Help In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Visual C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone here know how to maximize a form in the design view in visual studio???

Because whenever I click the maximize button (when Im running the program) only the form goes bigger and it makes my program look awful.

*I tried altering the size but whenever I enter big resolutions ex(1024, 768) the form overlaps the screen and the lower part was behind the taskbar (OMG! @_@).

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP ME!!!

Comment: I think you are running into Microsoft's lame user interface designers.  I don't have Visual Studio 2010, but even in Windows 7 there are many tiny little dialog boxes that cannot be resized at all.  That's just laziness on the part of Microsoft's coders.

Answer (score 1):

The WinForms designer allows you to stretch your form to the maximum allowed window size for Windows, and you can use the scroll bars if your screen is not large enough to view the entire form. This will allow you to design for larger resolutions. However, the deeper problem is that you need to learn about proper control [anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) in a form to compensate for different screen resolutions. I also suggest reading up on Windows UI design guidelines (email me and I can send you the Windows 7 UX Guide).

Comment: Here are the images http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/321032_271281839551451_100000089120007_1166703_6111218_n.jpg (NORMAL VIEW)

Comment: (MAXIMIZED VIEW) http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/321032_271281829551452_100000089120007_1166702_1450256_n.jpg
I want to use the extra space when Im maximizing it. But I don't know how.